# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to upload multiple files to specific directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

In ASP.NET Core Web API, I have two models:

```
public class Employee
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeCode { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeAttachment> EmployeeAttachments { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeAttachment
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EmployeeId")]
    public Guid? EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FileType { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

An employee will have several attached files. The file will be stored in this directory in the Web API.

Resources -> Attachments

Then I have this DTO.

DTO:

```
public class EmployeeDetailRequestDto
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeCode { get; set; }
    public Guid? EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FileType { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}
```

BaseResponse:

```
public class BaseResponse
{
    public string ResponseCode { get; set; }
    public string ResponseDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
CreateMap<EmployeeDetailRequestDto, Employee>().ReverseMap();
```

Then eventually put everything into the service.

Service.

Interface:

```
public interface ICreateEmployeeAsync
{
    Task<BaseResponse> CreateEmployeeAsync(EmployeeDetailRequestDto model);
}


public async Task<BaseResponse> CreateEmployeeAsync(EmployeeDetailRequestDto model) : ICreateEmployeeAsync
{
    var response = new BaseResponse();
    using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
    {
            var employee = _mapper.Map<Employees>(model);

                employee.FirstName = model.FirstName,
                employee.LastName = model.LastName,
                employee.EmployeeCoder = model.EmployeeCode

        // Insert Employee Data into the DB
                _context.Employees.Add(employee);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

               var folderName = Path.Combine("Resources", "Attachments");
               var pathToSave = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), folderName);
             foreach (var singleAttachemnt in model)
             {
                EmployeeAttachment res = new EmployeeAttachment();
                res.EmployeeId = employee.Id;
                res.FileType = singleAttachemnt.FileType;
                res.FileName = singleAttachemnt.FileName;
                res.FileName = singleAttachemnt.FilePath;

        // Insert Attachment Data into the DB
                _context.EmployeeAttachments.Add(res);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
              }
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Created;
                response.Successful = true;
                response.Data = _mapper.Map<BaseResponse>(employee);
                response.Message = "Employee created successfully!";
                transaction.Complete();

        return response;
    };
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
public async Task<ActionResult<BaseResponse>> CreateEmployeeAsync([FromBody] EmployeeDetailRequestDto model)
{
    var result = await _employeeProfileService.CreateEmployeeAsync(model);
    return StatusCode(result.StatusCode, result);
}
```

I got this error:

> Error CS1579 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'EmployeeDetailRequestDto' because 'EmployeeDetailRequestDto' does not contain a public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator'

and **model** is highlighted in **var singleAttachemnt in model**

How do I resolve this error, and also save the attachments into the specified folder.
Then, FileName, FileType and FilePath into the DB?

Thanks

Comment: `model` is of type `EmployeeDetailRequestDto` which doesn't implement `IEnumerable`

Comment: @RyanWilson - How do I sort this out, and also upload the files into the specified directory?

Comment: `Employee` is the class which has an `Enumerable` of attachments, you could get that object and use the `foreach` on its property `EmployeeAttachments `

Comment: You can try to `GetEnumerator` with `Employee`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, **model** is of type **EmployeeDetailRequestDto** which does not have any collections in it.  EmployeeDetailRequestDto represents a single attachment for an Employee.  It's only in your database entity **Employee** that you have an Attachments collection.

What you likely want to do is add an EmployeeAttachmentRequestDto collection to your EmployeeDetailRequestDto, and then loop on that.

Comment: Yes. How do I go a about that.